# A Divisive Subject

Tags: wordplay, cryptic-clues

> Setters' subject of squabbling: one out of Celtics' and cryptocurrencies' conversion. (7,4,11)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is:

> "one out of Celtics' and cryptocurrencies' conversion" means "take `I` out of an anagram of `CELTICSCRYPTOCURRENCIES`", and that gives **CRYPTIC CLUE CORRECTNESS** (the "setters' subject of squabbling").

Comment: Indeed, well done! Inspired by [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/54249518#54249518).