# Insurrection in Britain

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Without remorse from the very start, Briton ousted Theresa, then maltreated someone else; dies (7, 3, 5, 3, 4)

Comment: Woah! This is some next level.
Not only answer, but we have to figure out question as well XD

Comment: hmm, that is already the question though. however, I'm not the first one who has done this before. I'll link the inspirations when this is solved.

Comment: (indeed, cryptic clues are a specific type of puzzle; go check them out if you wish :0)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The answer is

> Another one bites the dust

Explanation:

> It's an anagram (indicated by "maltreated") of BRITON OUSTED THERESA THEN minus R (first letter of Remorse). The definition is "someone else dies".

Comment: Bravo. If anyone is curious, the inspirations were [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/95212/cryptic-quote-from-a-press-conference?r=SearchResults) and [Avi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98354/a-divisive-subject?r=SearchResults). :D

Comment: You solved that within an hour?! Insane!